# Is the push-forward of the pull-back of a regular section still regular?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, grassmannian

I refer to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/691864/404858) for definitions.

Let $X$ be a smooth projective uniruled variety covered by lines, $Pic X=\mathbb Z$, and let $L=\mathcal O(1)$ (if it's simpler, $X$ is just an isotropic Grassmannian). Consider the incidence diagram
$$
X \longleftarrow I=\{(x,l) \in X \times G(\mathbb P^1,X): x \in l\} \longrightarrow G(\mathbb P^1,X)
$$
where $G(\mathbb P^1,X)$ is the variety parametrizing the lines contained in $X$. We denote the projections by $p:I \to X$ and $q: I \to G(\mathbb P^1,X)$. Now, suppose that $s \in \Gamma(X,L)$ is a regular section, that is such that
$$
codim (Z(s) \subset X)=1
$$
where $Z(s)=\{x \in X: s(x)=0\}$. I know that $q_* p^* L=Q$ where $Q$ is the dual of the tautological bundle in the Grothendieck notation, I want to study the codimension of
$$
Z(q_* p^* s) \subset G(\mathbb P^1, X).
$$
Any idea or hint on how to prove or disprove that such a codimension is 2?

Comment: "where G(P1,X) is the variety parametrizing the lines contained in X"- what do you mean by this?

Comment: that a point of $G(\mathbb P^1,X)$ is given by a line in $X$. If $X=\mathbb P^n$, then $G(\mathbb P^1,X)$ is the Grassmannian of lines of $\mathbb P^n$

Comment: In projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$ or affine space $\mathbb{A}^n_k$ we may speak of "lines" - but for a general projective variety $X \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n_k$ - there is no such notion.

Comment: you, right: I have to be more precise by saying that my variety is uniruled